# BLE iOS app - discrepancy while sampling at high rate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using a nordic nrf51822 device and trying to communicate to it via an iOS app with BLE.

When the device sampling rate is set high - I'm able to read data at that frequency for about 5 to 7 seconds. After that time period, it samples at that frequency but doesn't update as often.

I tested the device with my app as well as the nordic tool-box HRM iOS app. It acts the same way in both the applications.

So my question is: Does this have to do anything with the CB framework or iOS environment?
or Does it have to do something with the sensor/device?

***or Does connection interval in iOS BLE change by any chance?***

Comment: I'm wondering if it takes too much memory.

Comment: Vetri, sorry if this is a silly question, but have tried their website which lists a number of tools developed for their products? https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-Smart-Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF51822. Maybe you find some pre-backed app you can use to help you work out what is going on?

Comment: Even their own app displays this behavior.@Lumialxk and when I built the app the memory consumption was constant in the log.

Comment: @user3069232 Yes, I have tried their toolbox app and tested in it too; same behavior. Wondering what could be the problem - hardware or software or a combination of both. Hope someone provides a solution or guides to it ^_^ Appreciate your help